# Как заменить текст в подключаемом со стороннего сайта js?

Tags: php

Имеется виджет статуса заказов, подключающийся к сайту на WordPress следующим кодом

```html
Шаг 1. Поместите код на страницу вашего сайта перед закрывающим тегом </body> 
<!-- LiveSklad Widget -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Задаем параметры виджета при загрузке
window.liveskladOptions = {
// Ключ апи, индивидуально сгенерированный для вас
api_key: "****"
};
(function() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.async = true;
script.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://')
+ 'my.livesklad.com/static/widget.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
})();
</script>
<!-- /LiveSklad Widget -->
Шаг 2. Добавьте на страницу контейнер виджета в нужное вам место
<div id="livesklad-widget"></div>
```

код скрипта

```html
var created = false,
  url = "",
  _createLSWidget = function() {
    function createWidget(config) {
      if (config && config.widget_url) {
        url = config.widget_url;
      }
      if (!config || !config.api_key) return;

      var Widget = {
        widgetElement: null,
        show: function() {
          this.widgetElement = document.getElementById("livesklad-widget");
          if (!this.widgetElement) return;

          var height = config.height ? config.height : "230px",
            width = config.width ? config.width : "300px",
            // Р§С‚РѕР±С‹ Р·Р°РїСѓСЃС‚РёС‚СЊ СЃ localhost: url : '/static/widget.html'
            widget_url =
              (url ? url : "https://my.livesklad.com/static/widget.html") +
              "?key=" +
              config.api_key;

          for (var key in config) {
            if (key !== "api_key")
              widget_url +=
                "&" +
                key +
                "=" +
                (config[key] === "object"
                  ? JSON.stringify(config[key])
                  : typeof config[key] === "string"
                  ? config[key].replace("#", "")
                  : config[key]);
          }
          delete config.width;
          delete config.height;
          widget_url = encodeURI(widget_url);
          this.widgetElement.innerHTML =
            ' \
                        <iframe id="widget_iframe" src="' +
            widget_url +
            '" scrolling="auto" width="' +
            width +
            '" height="' +
            height +
            '" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

          // document.body.insertBefore(this.widgetElement, document.body.nextSibling);
          this.widgetElement.style.display = "block";
          created = true;
        }
      };
      Widget.show();
    }
    createWidget(window.liveskladOptions);
  };
window.createLSWidget = _createLSWidget;

window.onload = function() {
  if (!created) {
    window.createLSWidget();
  }
};
```

подскажите пожалуйста как посредством php убрать надпись: Создано на платформе LiveSklad

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если нельзя убрать, можно хотя бы как-нибудь поверх вывести слой, который просто белым квадратиком закроет этот текст)

Comment: Средствами php никак не убрать. Средствами js убрать может быть можно, но почитайте лицензионное соглашение, убирая эту надпись, вы можете его нарушить

Comment: а если его просто перекрыть каким то слоем поверх? по факту я как бы его не убирал, просто её не видно из-за моего кривого стиля?)

Comment: А зачем её убирать? Ребята старались, делали что то для Вас... Может для начала стоит у них спросить можно ли убирать копирайт или нет?

Comment: я за старания так-то ребятам денежку ежемесячно плачу что-бы пользоваться этой системой. просто не нравится мне как виджет выглядит с этой надписью.